# How to implement RecyclerViewPager in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am trying to implement [RecyclerViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/buyi/RecyclerViewPagerIndicator)  in my project, but I can't get it to work.

I work with Kotlin and AndroidX

I expect send a array with text and images from database and show in [RecyclerViewPager](https://github.com/lsjwzh/RecyclerViewPager), something like tinder.

Comment: are you satisfied with following answer? do you need any help?

Comment: @user158
Yes,I had tried with [AppIntro](https://github.com/AppIntro/AppIntro) but [dotsindicator](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator) is a better solution although View Pager 2 is new to me

Comment: that is not big deal, do you want an working example with my answer?

Comment: try to implement ViewPager2 as in [Early Introduction of ViewPager2](https://blog.usejournal.com/early-introduction-of-viewpager2-ff38c60d2169) and I have problems with the text,and when impelemnt
dotsindicator show error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.SpringDotsIndicator cannot be cast to com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.WormDotsIndicator
        at com.Ange1D.viewpager2pagerindicator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:17)`
My repository is this [ViewPager2PagerIndicator](https://github.com/Ange1D/ViewPager2PagerIndicator)

Comment: this is due to you are using two different classes one `WormDotsIndicator` and other `SpringDotsIndicator`. Make sure you are having same type in both xml and Kotlin code? Do you need an working example?

Comment: Yes, I need a example

Comment: okay I'll give you one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [dotsIndicator](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator), since it

- supports `ViewPager 2` which is based on `RecyclerView`
- is maintained, one you picked is not (project seems abandoned)
- is written in `Kotlin`

Example:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.WormDotsIndicator
        android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupViewPager2()
    }

    private fun setupViewPager2() {
        val viewPager2 = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.view_pager_2)
        val dotsIndicator = findViewById<WormDotsIndicator>(R.id.dots_indicator)

        viewPager2.adapter = PagerAdapter(this)
        dotsIndicator.setViewPager2(viewPager2)
    }
}
```

**PagerAdapter.kt**

```
class PagerAdapter(fa:FragmentActivity): FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0 -> SampleFragment.newInstance("One", "desc 1")
            1 -> SampleFragment.newInstance("Two", "desc 2")
            2 -> SampleFragment.newInstance("Three", "desc 3")
            else -> throw Exception("No such position")
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".SampleFragment">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_header"
        tools:text="Header 1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
        tools:text="Desc 1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**SampleFragment.kt**

```
class SampleFragment : Fragment() {

    private var header: String? = null
    private var desc: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            header = it.getString(ARG_Header)
            desc = it.getString(ARG_Desc)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false)
        setView(view)
        return view
    }

    private fun setView(view:View){
        val headerText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_header)
        headerText.text = header
        val descText = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_desc)
        descText.text = desc

    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            SampleFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_Header, param1)
                    putString(ARG_Desc, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, add this in my project and I made this example [ViewPager2PagerIndicator](https://github.com/Ange1D/ViewPager2PagerIndicator)